# Where can I see all the differences between JRE versions?

Tags: java

Internet is full of blogs explaining the most important new features of Java 8 but reading the *javadoc* you find lots of new features on every corner (default methods on most interfaces).

You may be surprised by finding *new* features in Java 7, 6 or even 5 from time to time. Small precious stones hidden from plain sight.

Is there a web site with that provides a full comparison between JRE versions?

**EDIT**: I insist I want to see all the differences.

Here is an example: `ThreadLocal` class is there since Java 1.2 but in Java 1.5 `remove` method was added to.

Comment: are you asking about jdk releases or jre releases?

Answer (score 2):

This blog [post](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074087/core-java/jdk-7--new-interfaces--classes--enums--and-methods.html) lists some of the API changes in JDK 7. It was prepared by a Groovy script that searches for Since values in online JavaDocs. You can reuse this script to find changes in other major releases too.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at these for getting the idea of **Java Versions** history along with their **major features**, I hope it helps :-

**[Java Version History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)**

**[Java Versions,Features and History](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-features-and-history/)**

If you want to get more insight about the **Update Release Notes of Java™ SE Development Kit**, then you will have to search on the Official website of Oracle for the JDK release notes.
 The release note of Java SE 7 is available at

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u-relnotes-515228.html

A Sample release note of Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 60 (JDK 7u60) is available at

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u60-relnotes-2200106.html

Comment: That may be useful but is the kind of list Internet is full of. I am talking about small changes, not the big ones. I'll edit the question to add an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the release notes of every update. Here is the link for Java 7 release notes: [Java SE 7 update Release Notes.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u-relnotes-515228.html)
Is it what you want?

Comment: I want a comparison of API versions, not a huge change log organized chronologically release by release full of bug fixes that don't affect the API definitions.